# How can I find out cron implementation on Ubuntu?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, cron

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) says

> With the advent of the GNU Project and Linux, new crons appeared. The
>   most prevalent of these is the Vixie cron, originally coded by Paul
>   Vixie in 1987. Version 3 of Vixie cron was released in late 1993.
>   Version 4.1 was renamed to ISC Cron and was released in January 2004.
>   Version 3, with some minor bugfixes, is used in most distributions of
>   Linux and BSDs.
>
> In 2007, Red Hat forked vixie-cron 4.1 to the cronie project and
>   included anacron 2.3 in 2009.
>
> Other popular implementations include anacron and dcron. However,
>   anacron is not an independent cron program. Another cron job must call
>   it. dcron was made by DragonFly BSD founder Matt Dillon, and its
>   maintainership was taken over by Jim Pryor in 2010.[9]
>
> A webcron solution schedules ring tasks to run on a regular basis
>   wherever cron implementations are not available in a web hosting
>   environment.

On Lubuntu 18.04, I try to figure out what my cron implementation is, like for any other software installed, but fail:

```
$ cron --version
cron: invalid option -- '-'
usage: cron
$ crontab --version
crontab: invalid option -- '-'
```

I seldom have difficulty in finding out the version of a installed program, and wonder why it is hard for me? How shall I find it out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Try `man cron`. It identifies my system's (Ubuntu 18.04) cron as Vixie Cron.

Comment: Thanks. I remember commands and manpages can be out of sync, when having installed different implementations or versions of some software

Comment: No worries. You would hope that different implementations etc would install own man pages hey? In an ideal world...

Answer (score 3):

In the case of Ubuntu, it would be best to look up [which package provides the `crontab` command](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Fcrontab), and not the `cron` command, which might not even exist. The default is provided by the `cron` package (Vixie cron), but at least two other alternatives are also present:

```
~ aptitude search '~Pcron'
p   bcron-run     - Bruce's cron system
i   cron          - process scheduling daemon
p   cron:i386     - process scheduling daemon
p   systemd-cron  - systemd units to provide cron daemon & anacron functionality
```

Nether [`bcron`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/bcron-run/filelist) nor [`systemd-cron`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/systemd-cron/filelist) provide a `/usr/sbin/cron` binary ([`bcron`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/bcron/filelist) commands all start with `bcron`), but both provide the `crontab` command and an `/etc/crontab` file.

Comment: _The Debian GNU/Linux version_ of `cron` is a 1994 fork, called that by Ian Jackson.  https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17005677  Debian also aliases Bruce Guenter's softwares, which do not originally provide a `crontab` command but rather provide a `bcrontab` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the search function at [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) where you can find the current version for your release (though your local system might lag behind if you haven't been applying updates). That usually includes a link to the upstream package.

To find out which package, you might `dpkg --search /usr/sbin/cron` (or wherever `type cron` points you for the binary).

In the case of [cron](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/cron), you get pointed to [ISC](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/cron/)'s website.

If you want to investigate the source directly, you could also `apt-get source cron` to fetch the source code used to build cron for your system.

Answer (score 1):

There's no one solution that works everywhere for every package.

For Ubuntu 18.04 you can use their web site:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/cron

This has a link to a copyright file which shows it is Vixie cron.

You can also check the binary:

```
% strings /usr/sbin/cron | grep Vix 
@(#) Copyright 1988,1989,1990,1993,1994 by Paul Vixie
```

On RedHat 7 and derivates, a `strings` on the binary shows it was ISC

```
% strings /usr/sbin/crond | grep Cron | head -1
@(#) ISC Cron V4.1
```