# How to check the version of cron that is running?

Tags: cron

how can I check which version of Cron is currently installed and running on my host?  I can't seem to find a command that will allow to me see which version is running.  They all seem to just show that cron is running or not running.

Thanks!

Comment: What Unix are you using?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478769/ for how to better write such a question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be more specific next time and say the OS you're using, what you have tried, etc. I guess what you need to know is the version of the package that gives you the ability to schedule a cron, if so, in a RedHat variant like CentOS6 you can query the package as follows:

`[root@server1 ~]# rpm -qa|grep -i cronie
cronie-anacron-1.4.4-16.el6_8.2.x86_64
cronie-1.4.4-16.el6_8.2.x86_64`

As you can see above, I'm running version `1.4.4`. You can run `rpm -qi cronie` to see more info.